# Double http request in record scenario

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter

I recorded a scenario in a microservice application using Angular and Springboot, but I'm observing duplication of some http request like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9igR.png).

These two requests are exactly the same?!  Can I remove one?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please read the posting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and strongly consider adding more details, such as your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is one "golden rule": [well-behaved JMeter test must represent a real user using a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) with 100% accuracy.

So you should not be asking random people over the internet whether you need to remove a request, you need to check whether your browser sends 1 or 2 requests, you can do this using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or an external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

JMeter shouldn't generate duplicate requests, if you seeing 2 similar (or same) ones it means that your browser actually sent them so you should have the same network footprint in JMeter. If you don't want duplicate code - delete one and put another under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller).

Your application might use some [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) mechanism periodically sending [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests for updating a part of data on the page and you should be doing the same in JMeter